# Gradle jetty plugins how to run it on a specific ip address and port number

Tags: gradle, jetty

I have a web service which is executable with gradle *jettyRun* task. If I run it runs on *localhost:8080*. I want to run it on a specific ip address and port number. My current build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

jettyRun {
   reload = "automatic"
   scanIntervalSeconds = 10
}
```

Other dependencies are removed. I know about the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html) I just don't know the syntax. How to configure host and port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You need is:

```
//other plugins
apply plugin: 'jetty'

httpPort = 9000

jettyRun {
   reload = "automatic"
   scanIntervalSeconds = 10
}
```

As far as I know host isn't configurable - You just run it and it depends on os specific configuration if it's accessible from other hosts or not.

Comment: As I don't know gradle or Groovy script. Does it matter if I put inside jettyRunt {httpPort = 9000}? Cannot test it now, that is why asking.

Comment: I just tested. It works either inside or outside jettyRun{}. It would be really nice to know if possible to configure IP as well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, it works as stated in the docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html. When it comes to setting IP You can try to do it by setting this property `jettyConfig` pointing to file filled with appropriate configuration. What is good configuration for that is a jetty not gradle question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Opal answer, you can also run Jetty at a specific port by using below configuration in `build.gradle`:

```
jettyRun {
   reload = "automatic"
   scanIntervalSeconds = 10
   httpPort = 9999
}
```

or shorthand version `jettyRun.httpPort = 9999`

And for `jettyRunWar` task with following configuration:

```
jettyRunWar {
       reload = "automatic"
       scanIntervalSeconds = 10
       httpPort = 9999
}
```

or   `jettyRunWar.httpPort=9999`